# How to clear or reset inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, knockout.js

I'm trying to clear and reset my input and select fields using knockoutJS. below is a snippet on how it kinda works but edited for brevity.

Javascript Code

```
view = (function()
{
     var self = this;
     self.anItem = ko.observable(new AnItem());
     ko.applyBindings(self)

     self.addItem = function()
     {
        self.somewhere.push(this);
        self.anItem = new AnItem(); /////this doesn't clear the form
     }
})();

function AnItem()
{
   this.Name= "";
   this.Type= 1
}
```

Html Code

```
<tfoot data-bind="with: anItem">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value= Name" /></td>
        <td><select data-bind="options: pretendThisIsPopulated, optionsValue:'Value', optionsText:'Text', value:Type" /></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: addItem">add</a></td>
    </tr>

</tfoot>
```

Comment: can you add jQuery to your project? Using jQuery it would be a snap

Answer (score 1):

```
self.anItem(new AnItem()); //should say instead
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer

Comment: setting the item as an argument instead setting like an property is the proper way to set the observable

Comment: You can edit your answer so that the explanation is with your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can clear those like this.

**Edited**

```
view = (function()
{
     var self = this;

     var AnItem = function (name,type)
     {
        var $this = this;
        this.Name = ko.observable(name | "");
        this.Type = ko.observable(type | 1);
     };

     self.anItem = ko.observable(new AnItem("Name",1));
     ko.applyBindings(self)

     self.addItem = function()
     {
        self.somewhere.push(this);
        self.anItem = new AnItem("",1); 
     };

})();
```

Use `self.addItem();` to clear the data where you want.